# Search element in dictionary by mulitple conditions without looping

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary like one below (but with 10k key-value pairs):

```
test_dict={'2*foo*+':['5','10'],'3*bar*-':['15','20']}
```

Is there a way in python to find an element which `key.split("*")[0]==2`, `key.split("*")[2]=="+"` and `val[1]<15` without looping through the dictionary. Its easy to do by `for` loop, but in my case this is a part of a bigger code which is nested into another `for` loop, so it will take very long to finish.

Thanks,

Comment: The best performance improvement I can think of right now is to build another dictionary whose keys match the two conditions on `key.split('*')`, and whose values are lists of the corresponding values from the original `test_dict` dict, or the key-value pairs if that's what you need. In your example, you'd have to pass `('2', '+')` to that new dict, and then loop over the the corresponding listand apply your criterion on the value. The creation of the table would require some processing, but thanks to it using hashes, access would be way faster.

Answer (score 1):

As asked, the answer is no.  There is no way to test the keys and values of a dictionary without looking at each one in turn until you find a match.

However, if you build a more complex datastructure (possibly consisting of a series of dicts) so that entries are *also* indexed by `key.split("*")[0]`, then you would only have to loop over those elements.

(It does sound like you are trying to build an in-memory database though - you might well be better off just using a proper database, and relying on the caching to keep most of it in memory.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` with a `set()`:

```
test_dict={'2*foo*+':['5','10'],'3*bar*-':['15':'20']}

possibilities = list(filter(lambda x: int(x[0].split("*")[0]) == 2 and x[0].split("*")[2] == "+" and int(x[1][1]) < 15, test_dict.items()))
```

Comment: Isn't `filter` going to loop over the set?

Comment: this returns `[]` when printing

Comment: @Hrant fixed. `x[0].split("*")[0]` had to be casted as an `int`.

Comment: generally `filter`+`lambda` is a bit more slower than a clean list comprehension due to the function call overhead ...

Comment: I guess the same goes for `x[1][1]`. That way it works, thanks

Comment: @Hrant I just fixed that as well. Glad to help!

Comment: @Hrant this answer helped you please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You note that "this is a part of a bigger code which is nested into another for loop" so I suggest that you build an index of key parts before your outer loop.  Your indexes will contain sets of keys matching individual conditions.  Because they contain sets you can find fast intersections to find keys that satisfy your key condition.

```
from collections import defaultdict

key_index_num = defaultdict(set)
key_index_word = defaultdict(set) 
key_index_sign = defaultdict(set)

for key in test_dict:
    num, word, sign = key.split('*')
    key_index_num[num].add(key)
    key_index_word[word].add(key)
    key_index_sign[sign].add(key)
```

Then it will be easy to find keys in your inner loop.  Let's say you want to find all keys that have `num == '2'` and `sign == '+'`.  Find the keys by doing:

```
keys = key_index_num['2'].intersection(key_index_sign['+'])
```

**Note:** I have built three indexes, but if the three parts of your key are always unique you can build a single key index.  The code would then look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

key_index = defaultdict(set)

for key in test_dict:
    for key_part in key.split('*'):
        key_index[key_part].add(key)
```

And keys search would look like:

```
keys = key_index['2'].intersection(key_index['+'])
```